# How can I make sure a thread gets dibs after a certain Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, signalr, race-condition

I'm in a bit of a conundrum regarding multithreading.
I'm currently working on a real-time service using SinglaR. The idea is that a connected user can request data from another.
Below is a gist of what the request and response functions look like.

**Consider the following code:**

```
private readonly ConcurrentBag _sharedObejcts= new ConcurrentBag();
```

The request:

```
[...]

var sharedObject = new MyObject();
_sharedObejcts.Add(sharedObject);

ForwardRequestFireAndForget();

try
{
    await Task.Delay(30000, sharedObject.myCancellationToken);
}
catch
{
    return sharedObject.ResponseProperty;
}

_myConcurrentBag.TryTake(sharedObject);

[...]
```

The response:

```
[...]

var result = DoSomePossiblyVeryLengthyTaskHere();

var sharedObject = ConcurrentBag 
    .Where(x)
    .FirstOrDefault();

// The request has timed out so the object isn't there anymore.
if(sharedObject == null)
{
    return someResponse;
}

sharedObject.ResponseProperty = result;

// triggers the cancellation source
sharedObject.Cancel();

return someOtherResponse;

[...]
```

So basically a request is made to the server, forwarded to the other host and the function waits for cancellation or it times out.

The other hosts call the respond function, which adds the `repsonseObject` and triggers `myCancellationToken`.

I am however unsure whether this represents a race condition.
In theory, could the responding thread retrieve the `sharedObject` while the other thread still sits on the finally block?
This would mean, the request timed out already, the task just hasn't gotten around to removing the object from the bag, which means the data is inconsistent.

What would be some guaranteed ways to make sure that the first thing that gets called after the `Task.Delay()` call is the `TryTake()`call?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if you want to call something after task completes you can use ContinueWith

Comment: @Fake but isn't there a chance that some other thread retrieves the shared object before the `ContinueWith(Task)` is executed, thus finding an object where there should be none?

Comment: @AsPas - Always remove the object from the `ConcurrentBag` before trying to process it. Then there's no race condition.

Comment: But then there is no way for the host to access the object, should he still be on time.

Comment: @AsPas - I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry, I have updated the code a bit to try to express  my intent better.

Comment: The first thread adds an object and waits or times out. The second thread writes to the property of the object and cancels the delay task. The first thread then reads the changed property.

Comment: @AsPas - Oh, wow. I get it. This is a very weird way of doing it.

Comment: @Enigmativity how would you do it?

Comment: @AsPas You would need to provide a [mcve] for anything concrete, but I would hope that you can write a `async Task<Result> CallLongRunningAsync(Parameter parameter)` to do the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to have the producer cancel the consumer's wait. That's way too much conflation of responsibilities.

Instead, what you really want is for the producer to send an asynchronous signal. This is done via `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. The consumer can add the object with an incomplete TCS, and then the consumer can (asynchronously) wait for that TCS to complete (or timeout). Then the producer just gives its value to the TCS.

Something like this:

```
class MyObject
{
  public TaskCompletionSource<MyProperty> ResponseProperty { get; } = new TaskCompletionSource<MyProperty>();
}


// request (consumer):

var sharedObject = new MyObject();
_sharedObejcts.Add(sharedObject);

ForwardRequestFireAndForget();

var responseTask = sharedObject.ResponseProperty.Task;
if (await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(30000), responseTask) != responseTask)
  return null;

_myConcurrentBag.TryTake(sharedObject);
return await responseTask;


// response (producer):

var result = DoSomePossiblyVeryLengthyTaskHere();
var sharedObject = ConcurrentBag 
    .Where(x)
    .FirstOrDefault();

// The request has timed out so the object isn't there anymore.
if(sharedObject == null)
  return someResponse;

sharedObject.ResponseProperty.TrySetResult(result);
return someOtherResponse;
```

The code above can be cleaned up a bit; specifically, it's not a bad idea to have the producer have a "producer view" of the shared object, and the consumer have a "consumer view", with both interfaces implemented by the same type. But the code above should give you the general idea.

Comment: But how will the producer know whether the consumer timedout or accepted the supplied result?

Comment: @AsPas: Why would the producer need to know?

Comment: Because depending on whether the result was accepted a different result should be returned in the consumer function. I've read the docs about TaskCompletionSource though. And I could attempt to call TrySetCancel from the producer side, if the request timed out. So the TrySetResult function will return false, if the task is already in canceled, faulted or RanToCompletion state.  But yeah, your tip is certainly the way to go as it eliminates any race conditions and makes synchronization very easy. Thank you.